# _ViewImports.cshtml @layout is available only in components folder

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I use `@layout` in `_ViewImports.cshtml` outside the `components` folder?
I really don't like feature by type folder structure, so, i'm trying to achieve this structure:
[image]

The problem is that `@layout` only works if the folder name is `components`

Any way to do this?

BTW: `Login/Index.razor` `@layout` works

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

> Components can be authored in Razor Components apps using the .cshtml
>   file extension as long as the files are identified as Razor Component
>   files using the _RazorComponentInclude MSBuild property.

Inside .csproj

```
<_RazorComponentInclude>Components\**\*.cshtml</_RazorComponentInclude>
```